# Populating an Array in C

Tags: c, arrays, memory

I'm new to programming and am having difficulty with arrays. I've declared the array but when I go to print an element of the array I get a very different number (possibly a memory address?).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int array[10] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

    printf("%d", &array[3]);
    return 0
}
```

Then it prints 6356748 instead of "3." What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if one of the answers has been useful, please convalid it

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
printf("%d", array[3]);
```

When you use `&variable`, it returns the address of the variable.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are printing the address:

`printf("%d", &array[3]);` // note the use of &

Use this to print the value:

`printf("%d", array[3]);` // no & used

Answer (score 2):

using `&array[3]` you are not refearing to the value `array[3]` (you are using a pointer, that is a reference to an address of the memory, you will know it later). You simply need to remove the `&`  :

```
printf("%d", array[3]);
```